# Why Selenium C# code is not running after publish?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was doing NUnit test automation under Selenium C#. After everything, I published the code and after publishing it, when I run the dll file with `dotnet test {path of DLL}`, command I am getting the following error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchDriverException : Unable to obtain chrome using Selenium Manager; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location

OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Selenium Manager process exited abnormally with 65 code: D:\export folder\selenium-manager\windows\selenium-manager.exe  --browser "chrome" --output json
```

I have verified the code and confirmed that the code is working fine before publishing. I don't know why I am facing this error after publishing. Please help me out.

I tried changing the chrome browser to Firefox, edge and all but it seems like this is an issue with selenium manager after publish.

I tried changing the browser and versions but no use.

Answer (score 0):

are you using webdriver manager ?? if you are using Chromedriver exe file which has a version higher than the browser version it will work fine, if you are using driver manager to open and control already installed Chrome then browser update can cause a problem.

Comment: Well if that's the problem then it shouldn't be running while I am testing, but here it works perfect while testing but doesn't run when I hit publish code.

Comment: what are you using chromedriver exe file?? if it works in debug then you may have a file in which property not set to content and copy always.